# Fitting rear cam to a pulse. System

Tags: camshaft, rear

How to wire rear cam into reverse light on Corsa 3014
But the wiring is the pulse that we have to splice into

Comment: What is the suggested diagram for the camera? then we may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: The camera is a dash cam and rear cam combined the dash and rear work all the time , but there is a red lead to attach to the positive connection ,on the rear reversing light so it activates the camera when reverse selected,also activates infrared with lines to assist parking
My problem is finding the live wire to connect to with it being a pulse system,and how to wire in the connection,an easy job on a traditional wiring system Rick

Comment: @user45632 - Please use the [combine accounts](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) procedure to bring your two accounts together.